# CSS min-height 100% page with content height 100%

Tags: css

I have created a page that has a min-height of 100% with a footer, as outlined http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

It works for the page-filling div, but I would like to have elements inside it which also take up all the height available to them.

Attempts:

- Adding `height: 100%` to them does not work. They will use the parent's height but there are other elements and padding etc so that's the wrong height.
- Making them absolute and set `top: 0px; bottom: 0px;`. This will make the div fill up the entire height, but if content is added the div doesn't get higher.

If this explanation is unclear, I have an example here: http://markv.nl/stack/quine.php

So the parent dictates a minimum height, as does the content. The highest of them should be selected. I've found this a formidable challenge; is it possible without javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, I am quite confident that what I want to do is impossible. Correct me if I'm wrong.

In my case, it turned out a fix was possible. I used the `position: absolute` to create the background pattern. Above that, I added the content in a `width:100%` div to make the page scale.

It'll only work for some applications, but I think a general solution is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without javascript. But you should not use absolute positioning with this problem. Use [this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) solution to have footer stick to the bottom of the page. And make content div min-height: 100%. With more content it expand and push the footer down and with little content footer will be at the bottom of the page and content div will be pushed up to the footer.

Comment: I think a problem with this is that the content div will be too high because there are other elements with a height inside it's parent and 100% includes their height.

Comment: (Maybe my example was a bit simplistic, but I need one div to be `min-height: 100%`, for which your approach works, but I also need one of the elements inside it to take up all available space).

Comment: In that scenario content div will be either right up until footer if he has less content than it fits in the screen, or if there is more content than it fits the screen it will push the footer down and expand to wrap around all of the content.

Comment: So your desired output is to have lets say content div which has 2 columns and a footer that is either below the content div if there is more content or just at the bottom of the screen if there is less content, but in that case content div should reach the footer. If so confirm so I can create a demo for that.

Comment: Yes exactly, thanks! I tried your solution here, feel free to adapt: http://jsfiddle.net/8ycSa/

Comment: Created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Astraldiva/L7YpN/). Think that it solves your issue. Found a great resource for that [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

Comment: In the example, the content (#main) does not reach the footer I think? (In this case it looks the same but for me there are backgrounds and margins etc). Thanks for all your help!